# python testing and unit testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a simple calculator program and want to testing it using unit test concepts and this is my code :

```
def add(x, y):
    result =  x + y
    return result

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    result =  x - y
    return result

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    result =  x * y
    return result

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        print("You can't divide by zero!")
        raise ZeroDivisionError("You can't divide by zero!")
    elif x == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        result =  x / y
        return result



def calculate(choice, num1, num2 ):
    # check if choice is one of the four options
    if not num1 or not num2:
        print("inputs can not be null")
        raise ValueError("inputs can not be null")  
    num1 = check_user_input(num1)
    num2 = check_user_input(num2)
    result = ""
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):

        if choice == '1':
            result = add(num1, num2)

        elif choice == '2':
            result = subtract(num1, num2)

        elif choice == '3':
            result = num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2)

        elif choice == '4':
            if num2 == 0:
                print("You can't divide by zero!")
                raise ZeroDivisionError("You can't divide by zero!")
            result = num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2)
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid choice!")

    return result
```

and i want to test calculate function using mock.

so i did this  :

```
def test_checkCalculate4(self):
        self.assertEqual(calculate('1',6,3), 9)
```

but this didn't work and filed with error :

```
self.assertEqual(calculate('1',6,3), 9)
AssertionError: 5 != 9
```

any idea about it and how i can do it ?

Comment: I notice that your if statement uses parentheses to denote the list `('1', etc.)`. I think this should be done with square brackets `[]`. Could that be the problem?
Other than that, did you check that your unit test actually calls the add method and gives the right parameters?

Comment: You are actually doing unit testing properly, but it is uncovering an error in your code. Probably, the error is in the function `check_user_input`, which you did not include in your code.

Comment: @Stimmot - parentheses denote a tuple, not a list, so no error here.